# how to break text at line breaks?

Tags: javascript, string, split

basically, i'm making a discord music bot, and i made a lyrics command for it:

```
const { lyricsExtractor } = require('@discord-player/extractor');
const lyricsFinder = lyricsExtractor();
const result = await lyricsFinder.search(track.title);
const lyrics = [];
for (let i = 0; i < result.lyrics.length; i += 2000) {
    lyrics.push(result.lyrics.substring(i, i + 2000));
}
```

it splits the lyrics at every 2000 characters (it's the maximum number of characters per message), but there is a problem: it's spliting the lyrics in the middle of the line. how could i make it split the lyrics only at line breaks? (sorry for my bad english)

i tried this, but it didn't work:

```
for (let i = 0; i < result.lyrics.length; i += result.lyrics.lastIndexOf('\n', i + 2000) !== -1 ? result.lyrics.lastIndexOf('\n', i + 2000) % 2000 : 2000) {
    lyrics.push(result.lyrics.substring(i, result.lyrics.lastIndexOf('\n', i + 2000) !== -1 ? result.lyrics.lastIndexOf('\n', i + 2000) : i + 2000));
}
```

Comment: [`Array.prototype.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: Hi @Tomas, just to clarify you want to either split it at the last new line `\n` between the 2000 characters and if there are no new lines within the 2000 characters then you want to push all 2000 characters right?

Comment: @SShah yes, exactly that

Answer (score 0):

Eventhough I initially thought that a `while` loop would be a much better use to solve this issue instead of the `for` loop that you used, I have attempted to see if I could resolve the issue using your for loop, but I could not come up with a solution. Therefore, I had decided to try resolve it with my original thought of using a `while` loop.

The reason why I would recommend using a `while` loop in this instance is because the position of the last new line character within your subset string may affect where you start looking at for the next subset of string, i.e. say you looked at the first set of characters between index 0 and 2000, and then you find that the last newline is in index 1900, then on the next loop you would need to look at characters starting from index 1901, which again is much more easier to control from using a while loop.

Although I am not in favour of giving out answers I believe the solution below will probably help you understand why the while loop would be a better for handling your issue:

```js
let lyrics = `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Elementum integer enim neque volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper. Ante metus dictum at tempor. Non sodales neque sodales ut etiam sit amet. Iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing commodo elit at. Ridiculus mus mauris vitae ultricies leo integer malesuada nunc vel. Velit scelerisque in dictum non consectetur. Enim ut tellus elementum sagittis vitae et leo duis ut. Proin sagittis nisl rhoncus mattis rhoncus urna. Non pulvinar neque laoreet suspendisse interdum. Aliquam sem et tortor consequat. Gravida cum sociis natoque penatibus. Placerat orci nulla pellentesque dignissim enim sit. Diam quam nulla porttitor massa id neque aliquam vestibulum morbi. Gravida arcu ac tortor dignissim convallis aenean et tortor. Mauris augue neque gravida in fermentum et sollicitudin ac.

Diam maecenas ultricies mi eget mauris pharetra. Tempor orci dapibus ultrices in iaculis. Venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus non. Massa tincidunt nunc pulvinar sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin. Purus sit amet volutpat consequat mauris nunc. Turpis in eu mi bibendum neque egestas congue quisque. Malesuada fames ac turpis egestas maecenas pharetra convallis posuere. Velit sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt ornare massa eget. Id aliquet risus feugiat in ante metus dictum at tempor. Odio tempor orci dapibus ultrices. Leo urna molestie at elementum eu facilisis sed odio. Vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt ornare. Mi bibendum neque egestas congue quisque egestas diam in. Cursus eget nunc scelerisque viverra mauris in aliquam sem.

Posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Semper auctor neque vitae tempus. Sed cras ornare arcu dui vivamus arcu. Faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec pretium. Eget sit amet tellus cras adipiscing enim eu turpis. Enim diam vulputate ut pharetra sit amet aliquam. Ullamcorper a lacus vestibulum sed arcu non odio euismod. Interdum posuere lorem ipsum dolor. Magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus. Id diam maecenas ultricies mi eget mauris pharetra. Facilisi cras fermentum odio eu. Fermentum odio eu feugiat pretium nibh ipsum. Et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin libero. Non enim praesent elementum facilisis.

Egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna ac placerat vestibulum lectus mauris. Lacus sed viverra tellus in hac habitasse platea dictumst. Dignissim suspendisse in est ante in nibh mauris. Non sodales neque sodales ut etiam sit amet. Sem viverra aliquet eget sit amet tellus cras adipiscing enim. Maecenas sed enim ut sem viverra aliquet eget sit amet. Congue eu consequat ac felis donec et. Lectus sit amet est placerat in egestas erat. Laoreet suspendisse interdum consectetur libero id faucibus. Vitae tempus quam pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem. Elementum sagittis vitae et leo. Gravida cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes. Nisl rhoncus mattis rhoncus urna. In pellentesque massa placerat duis ultricies lacus sed turpis tincidunt. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada. A erat nam at lectus urna. Cras semper auctor neque vitae tempus quam pellentesque nec nam. Turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna ac. Ut aliquam purus sit amet luctus venenatis.

Eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi. Id porta nibh venenatis cras. In est ante in nibh. Dolor purus non enim praesent elementum facilisis. Pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus. Senectus et netus et malesuada fames. Urna id volutpat lacus laoreet. Vitae turpis massa sed elementum tempus. Donec enim diam vulputate ut. Et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis. Ultrices sagittis orci a scelerisque purus semper eget duis. Venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu scelerisque. Id eu nisl nunc mi ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet nec. Massa placerat duis ultricies lacus sed turpis tincidunt id.`;

const main = document.querySelector('#main_lyrics');
const charactersToCheck = 2000;
let checkStartIndex = 0;
let checkEndIndex;
let lyricsLength = lyrics.length;
let checkLyrics;
let newLineLastIndex;
let splitLyrics = [];

while (checkStartIndex < lyricsLength) {
  checkEndIndex = checkStartIndex + charactersToCheck;
  checkLyrics = lyrics.substr(checkStartIndex, checkEndIndex);
  newLineLastIndex = checkLyrics.lastIndexOf('\n');

  if (newLineLastIndex > -1) {
    if (newLineLastIndex !== checkEndIndex) {
      checkLyrics = lyrics.substr(checkStartIndex, newLineLastIndex);
      checkEndIndex = checkStartIndex + newLineLastIndex;
    }
  }

  splitLyrics.push(checkLyrics);
  checkStartIndex = checkEndIndex + 1;
}


main.innerHTML = splitLyrics.join("<br/><hr/><br/>");

console.log("splitLyrics length = ", splitLyrics.length);
```

```html
<H1> Lyrics Split Test </H1>
<pre id="main_lyrics">
    
</pre>
```

As you can see I make use of the variable `checkStartIndex` within the `while` loop to more precisely control what position each iteration starts looking at for generating the substring.

You can also view the above code, here with the addition of multiple console.logs to better highlight what each step is doing: https://jsfiddle.net/wdg24sc6/1/

Comment: thanks! it just has one problem, it always splits the last line, even if the previous substring has less than 2000 characters. you can see what i'm saying [here](https://imgur.com/a/KpJA4nT)

Comment: @Vegnar again not trying to hand out answers to you for your work, so before I help resolve the issue you have raised with my solution, it would be good to see some proof that you yourself have attempted to fix this!, have you tried any particular scripts changes to the code I shared to overcome this issue?